# kubernetes localhost:8080 was refused with context

Tags: kubernetes, devops, alibaba-cloud

The Kubernets cluster is setup using Alibaba container service, there is no Issue with accessing the cluster using root account, when a new namespace is created and user is added to that namespace, it throws the error **The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused**

Here is the setup of troubleshoot

Defined the namespace **dev** and using get verb to display all the kubernetes namespace.

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    14d
dev           Active    56m
kube-public   Active    14d
kube-system   Active    14d
```

Added new context in the Kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl config set-context dev  --namespace=dev --user=user1
```

I should get an **access denied error** when using the kubectl CLI with this configuration file

```
root@kube-master:/home/ansible# kubectl --context=dev get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Instead of it's showing **The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused**

Without the **--context** it's works perfectly well

```
root@kube-master:# kubectl get pods -n dev
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox   1/1       Running   1          1h
```

Here is the kubernetes config view

```
root@kube-master:/home/ansible# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://172.16.2.13:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ""
    namespace: dev
    user: user1
  name: dev
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED

root@kube-master:# kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
          dev                                        user1              dev
*         kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, what i noticed when i execute the command

```
kubectl config view
```

The cluster is showing as empty

```
- context:
    cluster: ""
    namespace: dev
    user: user1
```

To fix this issues added the `--cluster`  information and modified the `set-context`

```
root@kube-master:/home/ansible# kubectl config set-context dev --cluster=kubernetes --namespace=dev --user=user1
Context "dev" modified.
```

and the context is set properly

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: dev
    user: user1
  name: dev
```

and i got desired results when looking up the pods with `--context=dev`

```
root@kube-master:/home/ansible# kubectl --context=dev get pods
No resources found.
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list pods in the namespace "dev"
```